# Convert digits of pi to array of characters (without decimal point) {C++ language}

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I have pi=3.14159...(type float), I want to convert this to an array of characters and store it as follows:

- a[0]=3
- a[1]=1
- a[2]=4
- a[3]=1
- a[4]=5

and so on..
I know the method to convert integer to array of characters. If anyone could give me the method or a way to proceed, it would be much appreciated.

P.S: This is my first time asking a question, so please bear my mistakes.

Comment: Clearly this is language-dependent but you didn't specify any language. What language are you using and what is your `pi` (e.g. a double?)

Comment: Naively, convert to string and explode at bytes, filtering out any non-numbers.  Eg, in PHP: [`array_filter(str_split(M_PI), 'is_numeric'))`](https://3v4l.org/Eu7iH)

Comment: sorry, the language is c++

Comment: How many digits do you need?  That can change the answer quite a bit...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? You're not going to be able to get much precision with this method, as seen from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways to achieve that. Here is how I did it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    size_t bufsize = 1024;
    char buf[bufsize];
    sprintf(buf, "%.20f", M_PI);
    for(int i = 0; buf[i]; ++i) {
        if(buf[i] != '.') {
            printf("a[%d]=%c\n", i, buf[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The main thing here is the use of [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). Note that it will have trailing zeroes and will **keep** the decimal point. The number of decimal numbers it will convert depends on the formating of sprintf; in this example I used 20 digits (hence "%.20f"), adjust this number as suitable. **This code is generic so it should convert any float point into an array of characters.**

Comment: That's not even the correct value for pi :)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It converts any floating point into a char array, so it should work regardless (PI or not). In any case, I have updated my answer, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: This method is very good, but accuracy is very bad. So, I calculated the value of pi and stored it as float pie. Now, how do I transfer that value to buf[]?

Comment: @ShankRam I hope this answers your question: if your PI value is in a variable called "pie" just pass that as the third argument to sprintf: "sprintf(buf, "%.20f", pie);". It works just like the printf function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you're needing this could change a little bit , but commom steps will be like:

1. Convert the PI value to string type
2. traverse the array and drop/remove the decimal point characters, usually this will need to recreate the array
3. You can also traverse the array with other methods, for example in C# you could use linq being pragmatic.

This is the easy way [C# code]

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace PiArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var piCharacters = from c in Math.PI.ToString().ToCharArray()
                               where c != '.' && c != ','
                               select c;

            char[] PIcharArr = piCharacters.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless if you're needing some 'micro-benchamark' this code could be improved with some more coding efforts, like using manual conversions or maybe pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<cmath>
#include<sstream>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream o;
    o << M_PI;
    std::string s = o.str();
    char * p = s.c_str(); // pointer to chars
}
```

But this is only accurate for a small number (10? 20? I don't know exactly) number of digits.

Comment: Does this strip the decimal point?

Answer (score -1):

```
    char chars[] = ".";

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
   {
      // you need include <algorithm> to use general algorithms like std::remove()
      str.erase (std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), chars[i]), str.end());
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was actually asked.

Comment: sorry if it is not , i think he just wanna remove "." from the string.

Comment: I think they also want to convert a float to a character array. However - it's not a hugely clear question so don't worry!